# Script works on jsfiddle but not on my site

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

The problem is the script on my personal site continues to show "Unable to retrieve your location" If anyone can help it will be much appreciated.
My personal site http://geolyft.com
https://jsfiddle.net/yotzincastrejon/z29esxf3/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p><button onclick="geoFindMe()">Show my location</button></p>
<div id="out"></div>

<script>
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

    output.appendChild(img);
  }

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  }

  output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clear your setting, it looks like you may have blocked your domain then from accessing your locaiton. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en

Comment: I noticed in Chrome recently calls not made over https (SSL) won't allow you to send a location. I recently had to purchase an SSL just to get my location showing on a Google Map.

Comment: what browser do you use? if Chrome, open DevTools (F12) on the left of the CloseButton (x) choose Customize (three dots button) -> more tools -> sensors -> try to set geolocation manually

Comment: I'm going to get a SSL. I read in the console looking at my website that getCurrentPosition no longer works on insecure origins